# スクレイピングしたものをcsvに書き出すと余計な " が属性につく。

Tags: python, python3, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

やりたいこと。
csvファイルをつくる
コンテンツは、htmlタグ付きのままスクレイピングしたもの。
しかし、余計なクォーテーションがついてしまう。

[image: 余計なquotation]

原因はstr()をつかったことだとおもいます。なぜなら、prettify()ではこのようなことがおこらなかったからです。
csvに書き出すためにどのような型に変換すればいいのでしょうか？

```
    for def_el in definition_list:
        def_list.append(str(def_el))

    sections_string = '<hr>'.join(def_list)

    return sections_string
```

このCSVファイルは、あとでHTML形式で表示する単語帳練習アプリにインポートする予定なので、htmlタグが必要です。

これがソースコードです。

```
read_input = input('Read Mode Enter file name e.g.) vocab.csv:')
write_input = input('Write Mode Enter name e.g.) appended_vocab.csv:')
with open(read_input, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file,\
    open(write_input, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    normal_word = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
        def_list = []
        if not normal_word:
            # scraping()は下の方にあります。
            definition = scraping(line[0].lstrip('\ufeff'))
            normal_word =+1
        else:
            definition = scraping(line[0])

        if not definition:
            print('no web for:' + line[0])
            csv_writer.writerow([line[0],''])
        else:
            csv_writer.writerow([line[0],definition])
```

読み込んだcsvファイルの一列目が単語になっています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

一般的なCSVフォーマットでは、値に`"`が含まれる場合、出力されるCSVテキストは

```
aa"b"cc -> "aa""b""cc"
```

こうなります。なので正常に処理されているように見えます。

読み込み側のソフトで`"`が含まれるデータが想定されているのであれば、そのまま読み込めるはずです。

Answer (score 2):

出力したCSVを後で読み込む時のことを考えると、基本的には suzukis さんが回答している通りクォートされたままの方が扱いやすいのだと思いますが、csv モジュールの定義を見るとパラメータで任意のクォート文字列に変更したり、クォートの挙動を変えることも可能なようです。

[CSV ファイルの読み書き - Python ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

> ```py
> import csv
> with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
>    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
>                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
> ```

[csv – カンマ区切りのファイル](http://ja.pymotw.com/2/csv/)

> **クォート処理**
>
> csv モジュールで定数として定義された4種類の quoting オプションがあります。
>
> - QUOTE_ALL
>     型に関係なく全てをクォートする
> - QUOTE_MINIMAL
>     (同じ dialect やオプションで設定されたパーサを混乱させる任意の)特別文字をもつフィールドをクォートする、デフォルトのオプション
> - QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
>     整数や浮動小数ではない全てのフィールドをクォートする、reader で使用するとクォートされない入力フィールドは浮動小数に変換される
> - QUOTE_NONE
>     何もクォートしない、reader で使用すると引用符はフィールドの値に含まれる(通常は、デリミタのように扱われて取り除かれる)